# Expected value of the log of the factorial of a poisson distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I found the expression for the expected value of the falling factorial of a Poisson distribution ($\lambda^n$) from - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment. Is there a similar expression for the expected values of the rising factorial and plain simple factorial? I am actually after the expected value of the logarithms of these quantities:
$$\sum_{u=1}^{X}log(u)$$ and $$\sum_{u=X}^{X+c}log(u)$$
where $X \to Poisson(\lambda)$.

Comment: If you just need an approximation, a normal approximation may work well. 

Comment: the expectation value of the plain simple factorial is obviously just $e^{−\lambda}(1−\lambda)^{−1}$, if $\lambda<1$ and divergent otherwise; the expectation value of the log of the factorial has no closed form expression.